# CosmoDB sequence generator

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, auto-increment, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am migrating legacy application from Oracle to CosmosDB (MongoDB 3.6 API). At current stage of the project and also with respect to current goals refactoring ID from sequence numbering to GUIDs cannot be done. I am aware of many reasons why this is bad design but it is what it is - I need sequence generation :(

I am trying to find a solution that will be reliable. What came to my mind is to create a collection `sequences` and inside of it keep documents such is `seq_foo` and `seq_bar` and so on. Upon each insert I would first do [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) and then insert with custom id.

What is the question I currently struggle finding answer: is `findAndModify` atomic if used on single document with eventual consistency?

In case it is **not** do I need to use multiple DB Accounts with different consistency levels or is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: FYI you're going to add RU cost to every operation by storing sequence numbers in a collection (the cost to read, then replace that document, with every single create operation elsewhere needing an ID). You also will have no way to prevent multiple simultaneous readers from consuming the same ID (though you will have protection against multiple writers, with the way concurrency is engineered). There's no built-in "identity" property or id-generator. Perhaps consider a stored procedure (though that will be limited to a specific partition). Or generate IDs outside of Cosmos DB?

Comment: There's really no "right" answer to this, but you might want to consider the use of some type of ID-generation service, where all of your insert requests go through a queue (service bus, etc). You'd then have 100% control over identity management.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thank you for answer. I was considering external service to cope with ID generation before we can migrate to GUIDs. From what you are saying is it true that even if I do: `db.sequences.findAndModify({query:{"name": "foo"}, new: true, update: {$inc: {counter: 1}}})` CosmosDB cannot execute it atomically even if I use strong consistency level? How would it be possible CosmosDB is ACID compliant within one shard?